# Unable to take screenshots on RemoteWebDriver - running tests thru Selenium Grid

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, c#, grid

I am running my selenium test thru Selenium Grid and I couldn't take screenshot on the node from my hub. I have followed the code from the Selenium HQ:

```
public class ScreenShotRemoteWebDriver : RemoteWebDriver, ITakesScreenshot
{
    public ScreenShotRemoteWebDriver(Uri RemoteAdress, ICapabilities capabilities)
    : base(RemoteAdress, capabilities)
    {
    }

    public new Screenshot GetScreenshot()
    {
        // Get the screenshot as base64.
        Response screenshotResponse = this.Execute(DriverCommand.Screenshot, null);
        string base64 = screenshotResponse.Value.ToString();

        // ... and convert it.
        return new Screenshot(base64);
    }
}


public static void takeRemoteScreenShot(string fileName)
{
    string currentDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("ddd, ddMMMyyyy HHmm");
    ScreenShotRemoteWebDriver webDriver = new ScreenShotRemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"), DesiredCapabilities.Chrome());
    Screenshot ss = ((ITakesScreenshot)webDriver).GetScreenshot();
    string screenshot = ss.AsBase64EncodedString;
    //byte[] screenshotAsByteArray = ss.AsByteArray;
    string dir = Settings.DirScreenShots;
    ss.SaveAsFile(dir + currentDate + fileName + ".png", ScreenshotImageFormat.Png);
}
```

My test is failing due to this error:

```
 Result StackTrace: 
at SeleniumE2E.Utilities.ScreenshotCapture.takeRemoteScreenShot(String fileName)
   at SEL_ADAccountReactivate2.SmokeTest.RunTest() in C:\Users\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\App\App\Tests\SmokeTest.cs:line 16
Result Message: 
Test method App.SmokeTest.RunTest threw exception: 
System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void OpenQA.Selenium.Screenshot.SaveAsFile(System.String, OpenQA.Selenium.ScreenshotImageFormat)'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SceenShotImageFormat` was a relatively recent change in Selenium for .Net core, can you try with ImageFormat if you're not using .Net core and if that works I would recommend upgrading your entire Solution (Including the grid) to a more recent version of Selenium.

Based on the [code in the solution](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/dotnet/src/webdriver/Screenshot.cs), it looks like it just switches it to the ImageFormat method regardless so .... not sure how it's useful as of yet.

Comment: Thanks @Paul Muir, I have updated my entire solution to 3.3.1 (I think that is more stable than the 3.4.0) then used 3.3.1 grid and it worked